# Does SQL Azure retry logic framework TransientFaultHandling ships with default retry policies?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

In process for my migration to Azure I implemented the Windows Azure AppFabric Customer Advisory Team "TransientFaultHandling framework".
http://appfabriccat.com/2011/02/transient-fault-handling-framework/

Here is what I simply did to my code (so easy it looks too good to be true) :

1/ Reference to `Microsoft.AzureCAT.Samples.TransientFaultHandling.dll` in my project (with auto imported namespace)

2/ Set a public function on a common DLL library which return a common policy:

```
Public Shared Function retryPolicy() As RetryPolicy

    Dim oPolicy As RetryPolicy = New RetryPolicy(Of SqlAzureTransientErrorDetectionStrategy)(10, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100))
    Return oPolicy

End Function
```

3/ Replaced all `oConn.Open()` with `oConn.OpenWithRetry(retryPolicy())`
and replaced all the others `Reader`, `Scalar`, `NonQuery` with:

- `oCmd.ExecuteReaderWithRetry(retryPolicy())`
- `oCmd.ExecuteNonQueryWithRetry(retryPolicy())`
- `oCmd.ExecuteScalarWithRetry(retryPolicy())`

4/ That's it

It works, I mean there is no errors, but as I'm testing against my local SQL Server I don't know if the retry logic is correctly implemented as I'm not aware of a way to test a connection failure.

I read a few examples of implementation of this TransientFaultHandling framework, and some included a custom created class for detecting SQL server errors code.
I did not created such a class to keep things simple, as i assume the framework is shipped with a good default behavior regarding retry based on SQL Azure exceptions code.

To the questions : 
- Is my code OK in case of a classic SQL Azure connection failure ? Or do I have to set up a custom class to detect the codes exception by myself ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transient fault handling framework comes with a few retry policies, including the SQL Azure one that you mentioned.  You should not need to make any changes to it to do what you want it to do.  The examples you see are there for reference so you could expand the framework if you wanted to apply it to something that hasn't already been catered for.